# Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I follow the 'Getting started' tutorial of chrome extensions, but I get the below error.

I search google, somebody say can't access 'executeScript' in content.js, but the error is from popup.js.

I had tried change 'chrome.scripting.executeScript' to 'chrome.tabs.executeScript', it didn't work too.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmLI3.png)

manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["storage", "declarativeContent", "activeTab"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.js

```js
let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor')

chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(data) {
    changeColor.style.backgroundColor = data.color;
    changeColor.setAttribute('value', data.color)
});

changeColor.addEventListener('click', () =>
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
      tabs[0].id,
      { function: setColor })
})
);

async function setColor() {
let {color} = await chrome.storage.sync.get(['color']);
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
};
```

[The whole extension code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-vtRsEa5WXrrhfUhAw3QnCjpJ86hLpV/view?usp=sharing)

[reference: chrome developers -> Getting started](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/)

Comment: Remove your extension from chrome extension page and then load unpacked your extension again.

Comment: If you HAVE added permissions in the manifest file and it's still not working, simply click the reload button on the extension's card on the extensions page. (No need to remove and reload manually).

Answer (score 55):

The permissions in your **`manifest.json`** is missing one item, which is `"scripting"`.

It should look like this:

```
…
"permissions": ["storage", "declarativeContent", "activeTab", "scripting"],
…
```

This is actually seen on [the Getting Started page here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/#logic).

Comment: I have added scripting yet getting the same error

Comment: After adding "scripting" try reloading extension or do "Load unpacked" again. It should work then

Answer (score 13):

You need scripting permissions to access scripting APIs. Add `scripting` to your `manifest.js` file.

```
"permissions": ["scripting", ...]
```

Answer (score 6):

You either need to migrate to manifest v3 or use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` instead of `chrome.scripting.executeScript`

Comment: Is it true that chrome.tabs is only work in content.js not in background.js ?

Comment: @Kanish chrome.tabs can be used in background.js, there it cannot be used is in content scripts (those injected into a particular page).

Answer (score 4):

Remove and load the extension back! Despite adding `"permissions": ["scripting"]` this is what I had to do.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the exception log "Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined" was pretty misleading.

With correct manifests, it happened, and it was because of typo in the to be injected function, like below.

document.body.style.backgrounColor = color;

corrected it to
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `chrome.scripting.executeScript` works in popup but not in content scripts.

This is a super simple popup example in React. You click on the button and it shows the page title.

```
export function Popup() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const onClick = async () => {
        const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true });
        const [res] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            func: () => document.title,
        });
        setTitle(res.result);
    };
    return (
        <div className="popup">
            <button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>
            {title}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]